# Implementing bell type notification using Signal R on asp.net webform instead of mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, signalr

I am planning on implementing a bell type notification on my website that notifies that user whenever there is a change on the database. Example is when the customer's order is accepted or rejected, the customer must be notified about it. I have been searching on google about that and the best i could find is using SIGNAL R but all the guides and tutorials are using asp.net mvc. I used asp.net webforms for my thesis project. Are there any tutorial or guides that actually implement SIGNAL R on asp.net webforms? Pleas help and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

SignalR notifications works almost the same in WebForms and MVC, the key is knowing where is the difference.

Taking [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/874240/SignalR-Database-update-notifications-in-ASP-NET-M) tutorial as an example, you can easily identify that:

1. Step 1: Enable Service Broker on the Database (SAME)
2. Step 2: Add Connection String to the Web.Config File (SAME)
3. Step 3: Enable SQL Dependency (SAME)
4. Step 4: Install SignalR from the nuget (SAME)
5. Step 5: Create SignalR Hub Class (SAME)
6. Step 6: Get the Data from the Repository (SAME)
7. Step 7: Register SignalR at startup Class (SAME)
8. Step 8: View Page (**DIFFERENT**)
9. Step 9: Create Partial View Page (**DIFFERENT**)
10. Step 10: Set Up the Database (SAME)

Your problem is summarized to following the example and find an equivalent of Step 8 and Step 9 between MVC and WebForms, which is pretty simple. This should aply for every example you see of SignalR and MVC.

Some tips:

- [Partial Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial) in MVC are equivalent to [UserControls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx) in WebForms.
- You might need to use [WebMethods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/8wbhsy70(v=vs.100).aspx) to call server side from Javascript/JQuery.

Finally, I found [this](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/526876/addingplussignalrplustoplusanplusasp-netpluswebfor) example that might help you if you still lost.